# Is it possible to use multiple validators in validType in jeasyui datagrid?

Tags: datagrid, validation, jquery-easyui

Is it possible to use multiple validators in jeasyui datagrid validatebox validType?

If it is there can I have one example please?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple validator for validate box validtype are available from version .1.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is your html input box

```
<input name="email" class="easyui-validatebox" data-options="required:true,validType:['validEmail','isUniqueEmail[\'#user_id\']']">
```

and these are your validation functions:

```
    $.extend($.fn.validatebox.defaults.rules, {
        // email address vallidation for uniqueness.
        isUniqueEmail: {                
            validator: function(value,param){
                   // code for unique email validation
                });
                return respond;
            },
            message: 'Email must be unique.'
        },
        // Eamil validation.
        validEmail: {               
                   // Code for valid email.
            },
            message: 'Enter valid email.'
        },
    });
```